# Web App works fine on locat tomcat server but giving 404 after pushing on shift

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-cartridge, openshift-enterprise

I have been working on a web app with spring mvc and jersey and almost complete the functionality. I was testing it on local tomcat server but today when i pushed it to openshift server its not working and giving me 404 not found. I have no idea whats wrong with it. What can be the prossible reason for this kindly help

Comment: What do the statuses say in the web console?  That may give you a clue as to what's going on

Comment: im jucst checking it in my browser and it just say 404 not found

Comment: try actually logging into the OpenShift Web Console (https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console) and see if it has some sort of status error with one of the cartridges or the application itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openshift server required a specific dependency to run webapp online defined in pom.xml and I deleted it accidently after including that dependency again my app has started working again. Here is the dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.Final-redhat-4</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```